# Express.js & Mongoose - check if request value is between dates

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to make an Express.js API with Mongoose. Below is route code that receives date in request parameters and determines some info about week day. Server should check if received date is BETWEEN two dates saved in database (`validFrom` and `validUntil`). I tried to make two conditions like in code below, but the schedule is not returned when using test values. I tested the API with `date` `2020-09-02`, `validFrom` value is `2020-08-31`, validUntil is `2020-09-05`.

```
router.get("/:date", async (req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);

  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }

  try {
    const date = new Date(req.params.date);
    const week = getWeek(date) % 2 === 0 ? "parni" : "neparni"; // even or odd week
    const day = format(date, "eeee", { locale, weekStartsOn: 2 });

    let schedule = await Schedule.findOne({
      week: week,
      day: day,
      validFrom: {
        $lte: date.getDate(), // conditions
      },
      validUntil: {
        $gte: date.getDate(),
      },
    });

    if (!schedule) return res.json({ msg: "Not Found" });

    res.json(schedule);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server error");
  }
});
```

Does anyone have similar case of comparison of dates from database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function call date.getDate() is returning the day only so it’s not matching. You should be able to just pass the date object but it depends on how you setup your date attributes in mongo

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yes, you are right. This is the solution. Thank you!